# Pass data to from one viewcontroller to another viewcontroller on the same view

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-markers, uistoryboard, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm building my first app and I have **two view controllers being displayed at the same time**. The first is my google maps and top on of that view is a panel(pod) I [found](https://github.com/antoniocasero/Panels/). The Googlemaps viewcontroller calls up the **panel** which is in a separate story board.

I'd like to be able to **pass data to the panel** view without having to use a segue. I have tried the segue approach but it totally replaces the whole view. Is there a way for me to pass Data to the panel without having to switch to that view alone?

```
extension MapViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate {
     func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

        guard let placeMarker = marker as? PlaceMarker else {return false}


        guard let panview = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "atminfo") as? PanelMaterial
        else {
            return false
        }


        panview.Titlee = placeMarker.place.name
        atmaddress = panview.Titlee ?? "Me"
        print(atmaddress)

        return false



  }

}
```

Above is my code, this is one the GoogleMaps ViewController, this is where I receive the info from the pin and try pass it to the Panel that is active in the same view. I'm able to receive the data when I put breakpoints, but passing the data whilst the panel is still active in my GoogleMaps View doesn't display.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *"I have two view controllers being displayed at the same time"* ... are you loading them via `UIContainerView`s?

Comment: @DonMag , No I am not. They just appear as they are. Let me put a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

you can also use singleton classes to passing the data to different controller or you can create object in appdelegate it can also used from any class.

like this:

Declare variable in appdelegate

```
var channelID = ""
```

you can use like

```
let kAppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
print(kAppDelegate.channelID)
```

Comment: Okay, i see how this works. Would I then pass the variable from the MapViewController to the app delegate then through to the panel?